# Mongodb service fails to start on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

When I attempt to start the mongodb service using the command `sudo service mongod start`, it doesn't work. Upon closer inspection with 'sudo service mongod status` the following is found:

```
● mongod.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2017-09-18 21:00:29 CEST; 7s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 21352 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAIL
 Main PID: 21352 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 18 21:00:29 zeus systemd[1]: Started High-performance, schema-free document-oriented databas
Sep 18 21:00:29 zeus systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAIL
Sep 18 21:00:29 zeus systemd[1]: mongod.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 18 21:00:29 zeus systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

The configuration file has been changed to the following:

```
# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /tank/mongo/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /tank/mongo/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

The mongodb user been given access to the `\tank\mongo`directory using the command: `sudo chown -R mongodb:users /tank/mongo`.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I was supposed to give permission to `mongodb:mongodb`, and not only that; the child folders didn't inherit the permissions, so I had to give the permissions at the folder levels specified in the config `/tank/mongo/log/mongodb/`, `/tank/mongo/mongodb`.

I leave the answer in case it might help someone who is in a similar situation.